# admin configuration with automatically add certain product to cart for free

Tags: magento2, system-config

I'm trying to create admin configuration with two SKU's fields, where later you can choose main product and second product will automatically add to cart for free.
So, I created **system.xml** file first:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="learning" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Learning</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="sku" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Stock Keeping Unit</label>
            <tab>learning</tab>
            <resource>Learning_Sku::sku_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="sku_first" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>SKU №1</label>
                    <source_model>Learning\Sku\Model\Config\Productlist</source_model>
                    <comment>First Stock Keeping Unit.</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="sku_second" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>SKU №2</label>
                    <source_model>Learning\Sku\Model\Config\Productlist</source_model>
                    <comment>Second Stock Keeping Unit.</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
```

Then i created **observer**:

```
namespace Learning\Sku\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CustomObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $product;
    protected $cart;
    protected $formKey;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
    ){
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $items = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $isFreeItem = 0;
        $isXItem = 0;

        foreach($items as $item) {
            // X is product id
            if($item->getProductId()=="5"){
                $isXItem = 1;
            }
            // Y is free product id
            if($item->getProductId()=="2"){
                $isFreeItem = 1;
            }
        }

        if(!$isFreeItem && $isXItem) {
            $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product_id' => 2, //product Id
                'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product
            );
            $product = $this->_product->create()->load(2);
            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            $this->cart->save();
        }
    }
}
```

And also **events.xml** for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="CustomObserver" instance="Learning\Sku\Observer\CustomObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

But it's doesn't working together. I don't know if I do that task correctly. If yes, how combine all this code? Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This event if triggered when order is already created, you can't add new items.

Normally this type of actions(adding free product) are taking place right after main product is added. In that way free product is displayed in cart and customer have better understanding of a process.

Try to use *checkout_cart_add_product_complete* event. But make sure that you are not adding free product multiple times.